# changing Firefox addon sdk toolbarbutton icons at runtimes

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the toolbarbutton library, because the normal widgets would not store their positions if I restart Firefox. 
Unfortunately I want to change the icon on runtime. With the widgets I did:

```
widget.contentURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8082/static/icons/eth_16.png";
```

With the toolbarbuttons I tried:

```
Toolbarbutton.image = "http://127.0.0.1:8082/static/icons/eth_16.png";
```

without any effect. The image seems to be only used when construction the toolbarbutton.

Also tried to destroy and recreate the button with a different icon, but that causes annoying flickering.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Which toolbarbutton library in particular are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eric Volds libary. https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib

Comment: This may be a limitation of the library - have you considered contacting Erik directly?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test and this should work as expected so I'm not sure what issue you're running into here.  Here's some example code that works just fine:

```
var toolbarbutton = require("toolbarbutton");
var timer = require("timer");

var TEST_ICON_M_URL = "http://www.mozilla.org/media/img/favicon.png";
var TEST_ICON_G_URL = "http://www.google.com//images/google_favicon_128.png";
console.log("TEST_ICON_URL", TEST_ICON_M_URL);

var options = {
  id: "test-tbb",
  label: "TEST BUTTON",
  toolbarID: "nav-bar",
  image: TEST_ICON_M_URL,
  forceMove: true
};

var tbb = toolbarbutton.ToolbarButton(options);
tbb.moveTo(options);

timer.setTimeout(function () {
  tbb.image = TEST_ICON_G_URL;
  console.log("switched", TEST_ICON_G_URL);
}, 5 * 1000); // 5 seconds
```

Is there more code you could post?  The problem must be somewhere else.